# Why captured sys.exit() code is different from the provided one?

Tags: python, c++

I have a c++ program which runs a python program using `system()` command. I have return some value using the error code using `sys.exit()` in python code. But when I capture the returned value back in c++, it differs from one I coded in the python program.

My python code: `test.py`

```
    import sys
    sys.exit(10)
```

My c++ code: `test.cpp`

```
    #include "iostream"

    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
      string str = "python test.py";
      const char *command = str.c_str();
      int value = system(command);
      cout<<value;
      return 0;
     }
```

when I run run test.cpp, I got `2560`
Why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard defers to C (C++17 to C11) for this aspect, and it has this to say:

> If the argument is a null pointer, the system function returns nonzero only if a
>   command processor is available. If the argument is not a null pointer, and the system function does return, ***it returns an implementation-defined value.***

Assuming you're using Linux or some other POSIX-y type system, the return code matches that of the status that gets populated by the `wait()` call.

It's not a simple mapping, since it has to be able to return all sorts of *meta-information* about why the process exited, above and beyond the simple exit code (think of signals killing the process, for example).

That means you probably need to use the same [macros](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) you would for `wait()`, if you want to get the correct values.

Specifically, you should be using something like:

```
if (WIFEXITED(value))
    printf("Normal exit, returned %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(value));
```

In your particular implementation, it probably shifts the return value eight bits left and uses the remaining bits to specify all those other useful things. That's an implementation detail so may not necessarily be correct but it's a good educated guess.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I wish I could downvote comments.  To spell it out for you: the bottom eight bits of the value passed to `exit` is being returned in the high byte of the status code (remember these APIs date back to the time when an `int` was only 16 bits).

Comment: @MartinBonner I know in this day and age you're not allowed to make jokes. I actually up voted this answer as it's perfectly correct. We grumpy programmers only want serious comments!!!!! It's okay bud.

Comment: @paxdiablo Perfect! I assume this macro will be valid for all hardware implementations.

Comment: Well, as stated, ISO C simply states that it's implementation defined. The macros are for POSIX-like systems, including Linux (and the BSDs, I believe). Windows, for example, states that it returns the value that the command interpreter returned.

Comment: @paxdiablo I couldn't return an exit code of value greater than 256. When I return sys.exit(257), the received code using the above macro in cpp is 1.

Comment: @Prayag, again, it's implementation defined. I would say, based upon what you're seeing, that the return code passed back to the environment is limited to a specific range so that the upper bits can be used for that extra information.

Answer (score 1):

Just as paxdiablo said, it is indeed `X*256` where X is the return code. Browsing through C++ documentation, the output of system *MAY* contain the error code, or may not, implementation defined:

Check: [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system). If you want to use the output and the return code on POSIX systems, you should be able to use [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html)